# JSF Message Validation not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Hi folks i want to realize different input fields and if some put nothing in the textfields ,show a message right from the textfield. And if the inputs are correct show a Dialog.

I am using primefaces 3.5 and jsf 2.1

Thank you for your help.

reg.xhtml

```
    <ui:composition template="/META-INF/templates/templateLogin.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="title">
              <h:outputText value="Register"/>
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="content">          
            <h:form id="regiForm">

                <p:panelGrid  >                 
                    <p:row style="height:20%">
                        <p:column><h:outputLabel value="#{msg['regi_firstname']}" /></p:column>    
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText  style="width:350px"   id="firstname"
                                     value="#{regiBean.firstname}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['regi_firstname_error']}" />                                 
                        </p:column>    
                        <p:column><p:message for="firstname"/></p:column>    
                     </p:row>




                     <p:row style="height:20%">           
                        <p:column><h:outputText/> </p:column>       
                        <p:column>
                            <p:commandButton style="width:350px"  type="submit"  actionListener="#{regiBean.showDialog}" 
                                         value="#{msg['regi_button']}" />
                        </p:column>  
                        <p:column></p:column>  
                    </p:row>  

                </p:panelGrid>
                 <p:dialog id="dialog" header="#{msg['regi_dialog_header']}" widgetVar="myDialog"  position="center center" >  
                        <h:outputText value="#{msg['regi_dialog']}" />  
                 </p:dialog>
            </h:form>

        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: If I put nothing into the text fields and click the button no messages are shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

p:commandButton uses ajax as default, so you have to update the panel or add the property ajax=false to let the page refresh and show the messages

Comment: If i add a update="regiForm" the messages are shon but the the method ist not called and the method also.